# Error with android.Media.mediaplayer

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I am using Android.Media.mediaplayer but whenever I am initializing the mediaplayer, its giving me an error not sufficient resources to perform the requested operation, error from the OMX layer.

***E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: empty_this_buffer_proxy failure due to HW overload
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: ERROR: Sending OMX_ErrorInsufficientResources to Client***

That's why it's not getting instantiated and also getting error like *E/MediaPlayer: Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x0, mCurrentState=0*

can anyone tell me why I am getting this error? and how to resolve this?